# Correctly shutting down subprocesses in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, signals

I have a Python server that starts multiple subprocesses via `subprocess.Popen()`. When I run a specific method on the server, I want to terminate all of these processes.

My approach to this was to keep references to all processes in a list ...

```
self.procs.append(subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd)))
```

... and send interrupts to all of these to shut them down:

```
for i, p in enumerate(self.procs) :
    p.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)
    print 'interrupted ' + str(i)
self.procs = []
```

However, this only works for some of the subprocesses. For instance, one of the processes that does not stop after this call is a bash script that has a `trap` function for SIGINT signals. If I manually start this script and interrupt it via keyboard, it correctly executes the trap statement and closes . When the server sends the signal instead, the script seems to keep running.

What could be going wrong here?

edit: I have also tried using the SIGTERM signal instead, which did not work either.

Comment: The usual signal to send for a shutdown is `SIGTERM`.  Often we might have a "grace-time" delay and send SIGKILL (like `kill -9`) if the process still  has not closed.  The interrupt might not work if the script is waiting on a child process to complete at the time.

Comment: I have also tried `SIGTERM` which still did not solve my problem. Also, I assume my problem has its root elsewhere since my bash script traps `SIGINT` specifically, but does not seem to execute the trap statement when getting the signal from the server.

Comment: Did you try `p.terminate()` or `p.kill()`?

Comment: Try to group all processes in a group and kill it. as mentionned here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true.

Comment: if you want to kill a process tree then use [the solution from @AliSAIDOMAR 's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4791612/4279) (if you don't need to shutdown the processes gracefully; you could send SIGKILL immediately)

Comment: I just resolved my problem thanks to Ali's comment, thank you all. I answered my own question for other people searching up on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your contributions, what worked for me in the end was the approach that Ali linked. I started all subprocesses with this additional parameter:

```
preexec_fn=os.setpgrp
```

And then called

```
os.killpg(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

`SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, `kill()` or `terminate()` alone did not work for my shell script. The script was internally starting two services (`sudo service start`) and was supposed to `sudo service stop` them in a trap function, which did not work as expected.

I actually had some more trouble with another process that wouldn't shut down - a Python server that was not deployed but simply started as a script. No idea why the `killpg` approach did not work with this one. I finally resolved the issue by having it write its pid to a file and later have the parent script read it out and `kill` that pid.